# Android Polyline App to map user's walking route

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-polyline

I am trying to create an app which tracks the user's walking route and accesses the gps to get their location. I will then draw polylines between these points to show the route. I was wondering how exactly I would loop to keep getting the points and then how to then put those on the maps to display the route. This is what I have so far. Will this loop work to put the points in a list? If not how would I go about doing what I want to achieve?

One small issue is that it is saying variable mContext may not have been initialized. This was after I added

```
public GPSTracker(){
       arrayPoints  = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    }
```

GPSTracker class:
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

import javax.crypto.spec.GCMParameterSpec;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    //array with latitude and longitude points for polylines
    public static ArrayList<LatLng> arrayPoints;
   // intent.putExtra("arrayPoints", arrayPoints);

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }
    public GPSTracker(){
       arrayPoints  = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    }
    public ArrayList<LatLng> getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");

                        while(locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                                arrayPoints.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return arrayPoints;
    }

    public ArrayList<LatLng> getPoints(){
        return arrayPoints;
    }
    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is disabled");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Turn it on in settings.");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }
```

MapsActivity Class:

```
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GPSTracker gpsTracker;
    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Location Location;

    public MapsActivity(){
        gpsTracker = new GPSTracker();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                new LatLng(40.0139, -105.1507), 3));

        try {

            GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(MapsActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

            // Loading map
            initializeMap();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initializeMap() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (mMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error: Unable to create map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

        }
    }

   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap mMap) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> arrayPoints = gpsTracker.getPoints();

        if (arrayPoints.size() > 1) {

            PolylineOptions polyline_options = new PolylineOptions()
                    .addAll(arrayPoints).color(Color.GREEN).width(2);

            Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(polyline_options);


        }
    }






   /* @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }*/

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * c  * A an return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help, tell me if  I need to clarify more or show less code.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to give you an idea: You can keep track of the latest added markers and return user current location based every once in awhile, and if the distance of user current latLong and the previous latLong marker is larger than a certain value, add new marker. iterate the process updating the previous marker and user current latLong. Just an idea, please give it a shot.